# Need to format char(4) hhmm to time only or text to look like hh:mm in sql

Tags: sql

In the script below,  How do I convert the column `HHMM` to `HH:MM` and
    convert it to 12hr clock?

The column is a `char(4)` and format `0000` - `2359`. 
    Just want time or text with a colon(:), no date.

Please note that I do not want date or seconds.  How do I do this? 
    Thank you for your help!

```
Select    
          th.[store] as 'My Store',
    --->  this column th.hhmm as Time, (I need this to format hh:mm)
          emp.[First Name],
          td.Type as [Total],
          Count(*) as Qty,
          Convert(varchar(50),SUM(Amount1),1) AS Amount
```

Comment: This is the script:                                                                                       Select    
       th.[store] as 'My Store',
    --->  this column th.hhmm as Time, (I need this to format hh:mm)
          emp.[First Name],
          td.Type as [Total],
          Count(*) as Qty,
          Convert(varchar(50),SUM(Amount1),1) AS Amount

Comment: please tag the database you are using

Answer (score 0):

You can use `substr` to do this in Oracle.

```
select substr(th.hhmm,1,2)||':'||substr(th.hhmm,3,2) from t
```

In SQL Server, you can use `substring`

```
select substring(th.hhmm,1,2)+':'+substring(th.hhmm,3,2) from t
```

[Fiddle with sample data](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b6cef/1)

Edit:

```
select 
case when cast(substring(th.hhmm,1,2) as int) < 12 then
          case when cast(substring(th.hhmm,1,2) as int) = 0 then
          '12'+':'+substring(th.hhmm,3,2)+' AM'
          else substring(th.hhmm,1,2)+':'+substring(th.hhmm,3,2)+' AM' end 
     when cast(substring(th.hhmm,1,2) as int) > 12 then 
     cast(substring(th.hhmm,1,2)%12 as varchar(2)) +':'+substring(th.hhmm,3,2)+' PM' 
     when cast(substring(th.hhmm,1,2) as int) = 12 then
     substring(th.hhmm,1,2)+':'+substring(th.hhmm,3,2)+' PM' 
end
```

Comment: vkp, thank you..that gave me the proper format...now is there a way to convert to 12hr format...i.e. 13:00 to 1:00pm at the same time?

Comment: you should tag the question with the appropriate database, which would make it easier for people to answer

Comment: I thought I did...it is sql server 2003, sorry

Comment: You can just say `>= 12` rather than the special case, right? And btw, `% 12` won't work for the 12am/pm hours. ;)

Comment: I don't think it handles the hour "00" as "12" though. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks vkp and Shawn!

Comment: This worked great!  I really appreciate the responses!

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It uses `LEFT` and `RIGHT` functions

```
declare @time char(4)='2359'
select left(convert(varchar(100),cast(concat(left(@time,2),':',right(@time,2)) as time),9),5)+
              ' '+
       right(convert(varchar(100),cast(concat(left(@time,2),':',right(@time,2)) as time),9),2)
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server:

```
right('00' + cast((cast(substring(th.hhmm, 1, 2) as int) - 1) % 12 + 1 as varchar(2)), 2) +
':' + substring(th.hhmm, 3, 2) +
case when cast(substring(th.hhmm, 1, 2) as int) >= 12 then 'pm' else 'am' end
```